# How to set flexbox child to parent height(100%) when i have only 2 child

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add 100% height to my flex childs. it's not working. I know that i give direction as `row` but some time i have only 2 child where i need to set 100% height.

Is it possible? if so what is the correct way to do it?

here is my try:

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.parent{
  display:flex;
  height:100%;
  background:lightgray;
  border:1px solid red;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.child1{
  flex:0 0 30%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background:lightblue;
}
.child2{
  flex:0 0 70%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background:lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">child2</div>
</div>
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/2wv4s560/1/+)

Answer (score 1):

You have set the parent height as 100%.

You would have to set the height with some absolute unit.

Check below snippet with `100vh`

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
header{
  height:100px;      
  background:gray;
}
.parent{
  display:flex;
  height:calc(100vh - 65px);
  background:lightgray;
  border:1px solid red;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.child1{
  flex:0 0 30%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background:lightblue;
}
.child2{
  flex:0 0 70%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background:lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Header goes here</h2>
</header>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">child2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with you. but I have a header as unknown size. it's a popup. even i tried as `height:calc(100vh-65px)` - not works.

Comment: Can you add the popup implementation to your code above?

Comment: @3gwebtrain I have updated my answer, it works with calc. Please check

Comment: I am sorry, I am  looking to prevent the scroll bar. Since it's a modal popup.